# Converting compressed data in array of bytes to string

Tags: string, scala, compression, byte, zlib

Suppose I have an `Array[Byte]` called `cmp`. `val cmp = Array[Byte](120, -100)`.
Now, `new String(cmp)` gives `x�`, and `(new String(cmp)).getBytes` gives `Array(120, -17, -65, -67)` which isn't equal to the original `Array[Byte](120, -100)`. This byte of `-100` was part of an `Array[Byte]` obtained by compressing some string using Zlib.

Note: These operations were done in Scala's repl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you've got arbitrary binary data, never *ever* try to convert it to a string as if it's actually text data which has been encoded into binary data using a normal encoding such as UTF-8. (Even when you *do* have text data, always specify the encoding when calling the `String` constructor or `getBytes()`.) Otherwise it's like trying to load an mp3 into an image editor and complaining when it doesn't look like a proper picture...

Basically, you should probably use base64 for this. There are plenty of base64 encoders around; I like [this public domain one](http://iharder.net/base64) as it has a pretty sensible interface. Alternatively, you could use hex - that will be more readable if you want to be able to easily understand the original binary content from the text representation manually, but will take more space (2 characters for each original 1 byte, vs base64's 4 characters for each original 3 bytes).

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Could you help me on figuring out what I could do in my specific situation to deal with not using `String`s. I am using Spark's KafkaUtils' consumer which returns a `Stream`, each element of which is String. [Refer here's last method](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/api/external/kafka/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$). So will I have to write a custom method that handles arbitrary binary data?

Comment: @KamalBanga: I don't know anything about that, I'm afraid - I suggest you ask a new question focused *just* on that.

Comment: Kudos to you. I took me some time to understand how Base64 can help. Now all puzzles fall into place, :).

Answer (score 0):

More like Java, but `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`, `java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream` and `java.io.DataInputStream` can be used.

```
import java.io._

val bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(cmp)
val zis = new InflaterInputStream(bis)
val dis = new DataInputStream(zis)
val str = dis.readUTF()
```

To go backwards,

```
val bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
val zos = new InflaterOutputStream(bos)
val dos = new DataOutputStream(zos)
dos.writeUTF(str)
val cmp = bos.toArray
```

Comment: No, but what if I have some arbitrary data that is being converted to `String` and I want it back?

Comment: @KamalBanga added description about it

Comment: That was really helpful. But when I am trying to do the first part, it gives me `java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream`. I [did this](http://pastebin.com/5rWefyFx) where `compress` [is here](http://pastebin.com/XwYWPDWq). Also, `compress` seems to be fine since `new String(decompress(compress("simple complex difficult".getBytes)))` returns `simple complex difficult`. Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: Also can you explain, how this can encode arbitrary binary data to String and get the binary data back from String.

Comment: @KamalBanga If you're using the Deflater format, use another set `java.util.zip.DeflaterInputStream` and out.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But I felt more comfortable just using Base64 as mentioned by Jon Skeet and it solved my problem.